# What is a workbook in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Seems like a noddy question, but I started doing some VBA and I need to store some properties in `CustomDocumentProperties`. The examples use `ActiveWorkbook` to get the workbook. Is the workbook the file you have open?

How then is it possible to have multiple workbooks? Workbooks is an array after all.

Is it only an edge case that ActiveWorkbook might change?

Comment: A workbook is the Excel file itself. A worksheet is the individual tabs inside the workbook.

Comment: Why is `Workbooks` a collection then?

Comment: Excel can have multiple workbooks open at the same time. The `active` workbook is the one with focus and can change.  The `ThisWorkbook` property refers to the workbook in which the code is running within.

Comment: Definitely *not* an edge case that ActiveWorkbook may change.

Comment: You may find [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-workbook/) to be useful

Comment: I just found `ThisWorkbook` which seems far safer then, if the `ActiveWorkbook` might be a completely different file you've alt-tabbed to @Fink